# I am not able to update and install anything in virtual box. It shows error

Tags: ppa

I am not able to update and install anything in virtual box. It shows error

```
Err:1 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com

Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'

Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'

Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: download.sublimetext.com

W: Failed to fetch 

http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to update your VirtualBox;

1. Download the newest VirtualBox Installer for your OS.
2. Run the Installer and choose the path of your installed VirtualBox instance.
3. Choose the appropriate options.
4. Run the updated VirtualBox.